# How to upload Firestore Cloud Functions from the Console?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

My project has cloud functions already running (pub/sub triggers) and a Firestore Database, too. For the first time, I want to trigger a simple Google Cloud Function as soon as a new document is created in a specific collection ("Users").

I cannot find how to upload these functions on Google Cloud Console or Firebase Console. The only types allowed and displayed are:

- HTTP trigger
- Cloud Pub/Sub topic
- Cloud Storage bucket

How do I upload my Firestore Functions?

Answer (score 2):

Uploading Cloud Functions for Firebase is done through the [Firebase command-line tools](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli). I recommend that you follow the [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), which walks you through the process.

To learn how to write Cloud Functions triggered through Firestore, have a look at the [documentation on using Cloud Firestore triggers in Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events), or the [documentation on extending Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions).